# Splitting shapefile with one layer to many layers for attribute table

Tags: shapefile, r, attribute-table, splitting

Not quite sure how to ask this question, I created a shape file using the rasterToPolygon function in R. It works fine except when I open the shapefile I only have one layer and my I cannot do anything with the attributes table because there is only one layer.

I was wondering if anyone knew how to split that layer so that each separate polygon would get it's own row in the attributes table

[image: R structure of the]

Comment: I'm not familiar with r, but it looks like you need a multipart to singlepart conversion.

Comment: this might be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42512431/how-to-separate-a-multipolygon-geometry-into-several-polygons-objects-after-perf

Comment: Thank you the multipart to single part conversion was what worked! It had me stumped for a while! Thank you very much!